# Talend Job is not working in Windows service

Tags: java, talend

I am using tRestRequest, tXMLMap, tLibraryLoad, tRestResponse and tSystem components in Talend job. It is working through Talend runtime (i.e., from command prompt).

But When I am try to run from Talend container service (i.e., Windows service). I am getting the following error.

```
javax.ws.rs.webapplicationexception http 500 internal server error
```

[image]